# Background music, my music is overlaying one another, I want the music to loop

Tags: swift

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class BackgroundViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = .white

    playBackgroundStartMusic()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    audioPlayer.stop()
}

//MARK: - Background Music

func playBackgroundStartMusic() {
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "IntroMusic", ofType: "wav")!))
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you ever have a problem of music overlaying ate views changes, simply put the audioPlayer.stop(), from the AVFoundation at your button that present your next screen, that way background music will stop and not play again.